# $x^2 -(2p+4)x + 3p+4$

Tags: geometry, quadratics

$x_1, x_2 =$ the roots

$x_1,p,x_2,...$ = geometric sequence

Find the 12th element of the geometric sequence

What i know is
$x_1+x_2=2p+4$

$x_1x_2=3p+4$

I get $-p=x_1+x_2-x_1x_2$

But how to solve for the roots and $p$?

Comment: Pls work on & edit your whole post, both on contents and formatting, and incl. the title. Lower indices are achieved with underscores. And there's a wrong sign in the sum of the roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

We have $$p^2=x_1x_2=3p+4$$

Solve for $p$

Comment: Is the answer p=-1 ? And the 12th element is -1?